# Create tasks on Laravel and Ubuntu server using Screen

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, gnu-screen

It's possible to add the task from HTTP request with Laravel and processing with ubuntu server using **screen** session, here some example.

I have a Website with processing feature like decode whole of encoded string and take up to 24hours to process it, but it's impossible to my user waiting until task end, so I want to ask it's possible to submit task from Laravel, and send to my server 'Ubuntu Server' and processing that task on Screen sessions, Save to screen, generate unique id, check progress on screen, and send notification to user email when the task complete?

Comment: Just so you know, your question is a little bit too broad. You may get lucky with an answer but for the most part best questions to ask here are the ones where you have code samples to share.

Answer (score 0):

Use queue worker to do your long running tasks,
[laravel queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queues)
and also post any code you have written so that I can help